# Collapse Control under a GridSplitter - Unwanted White space appears

Tags: c#, wpf

Given the following XAML;

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0"
            Background="LightBlue">
        <Button Height="30"
                Click="Button_Click">Hide Lower Panel</Button>
    </Border>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                  ResizeDirection="Rows" 
                  Width="Auto"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="0"
                  x:Name="Splitter"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="2"
            Background="LightCoral"
            x:Name="LowerPanel" MinHeight="25"/>
</Grid>
```

Where `Button_Click` is;

```
this.LowerPanel.Visibility = this.LowerPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Visible 
    ? Visibility.Collapsed 
    : Visibility.Visible;
```

This looks like this;

[image]

If the button is clicked before doing anything else, then it collapses as expected;

[image]

However, if I resize using the grid splitter..

[image]

Then when I press the button, the following happens;

[image]

Is there any way to make the lower element collapse correctly again after it has been resized?

Note: for the purposes of this question I've just used code-behind event handers and a button to trigger this, but in real-life it's done in the proper MVVM way with the visibility being determined by a bound property on the view model.

Comment: If you set the visibility of border to Visible again, what is desired height of border?

Comment: Either outcome would be fine - either back to the default or back to the size it was collapsed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, when GridSplitter is used, its rewrites the Height or Width properties of the corresponding RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions. In order to do what you want, you should to play with RowDefinitions.Height property, like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //gr is the name of the Grid
    basepr1 = gr.RowDefinitions[0].Height;
    basepr2 = gr.RowDefinitions[2].Height;
}
static GridLength zero = new GridLength(0);
GridLength basepr1;
GridLength basepr2;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.LowerPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        this.LowerPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        basepr2 = gr.RowDefinitions[2].Height; // remember previos height
        gr.RowDefinitions[2].Height = zero;
    }
    else
    {
        this.LowerPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        gr.RowDefinitions[2].Height = basepr2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks stukselbax, this provides the behaviour I was looking for. I'll have to work out a way to tie this in with my view model and databinding set up, which is where the real fun starts! Cheers again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mark one of the row definitions as '*':

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Hm, nope, that didn't seem to do it. It actually stopped it working in the one instance where it did work (before manually resizing).