# WPF ContentControl does not collaspe on Visibility change

Tags: wpf

I have a tab sequence that I want to be able to split into two regions or recombine into a single tab sequence.  The application will start off with one tab sequence

[image: Application initial state]

Allow the user to split into a second panel

[image: Splitting the tab control into 2 areas]

And recombine into a single tab control.

[image: Recombining the tab items]

At this stage, I should get the same display at the first image.  But, instead, the ContentControl does not Collaspe and space is left in the main Grid.  There is also a GridSplitter that devides the two areaa (white bar in image 2).  That seems to Collapse as expected.  Is there some trick to get it to get the ContentControl to Collapse?

Here's the XAML.  There's a boolean property BottomTabDisplayed which indicates if there are any controls in the bottom area:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl x:Name="ControlContainerTopTab" Grid.Row="0">
        <TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                    >
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            ...
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </ContentControl>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="GridSplitterTabControls"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Height="5"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Visibility="{Binding BottomTabDisplayed,
                                       Converter={StaticResource VisiblityToBoolConverter}}" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding BottomTabDisplayed, Converter={StaticResource VisiblityToBoolConverter}}">
        <TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedBottomIndex}"
                    Visibility="{Binding BottomTabDisplayed,
                                         Converter={StaticResource VisiblityToBoolConverter}}"
                    >
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            ...
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Edit 1:
And, here's the converter

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isVisible = (bool)value;
        return (isVisible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed);
    }
```

I just noticed something interesting, if the GridSplitter is unchanged, it works as expected.  If I move the GridSplitter, then I get the empty space.

Edit 2:
Snoop changes when moving the GridSplitter

[image: Before moving the GridSplitter] 
[image: After moving the GridSplitter]

Comment: this looks like your problem and solution ; 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055637/collapse-control-under-a-gridsplitter-unwanted-white-space-appears

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your code for VisiblityToBoolConverter, you will very likely see it is returning Hidden instead of Collapsed

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.  I added the converter code to the post.  Also, I just realized moving the GridSplitter changes the resulting functionality.

Comment: can you drop a breakpoint and check the value of BottomTabDisplayed?

Comment: Yes, I questioned that myself.  I've walked through it and the value looks to be as expected.  The GridSplitter and the ContentControl share the same property for changing the Visibility.  The GridSplitter always collapses while the ContentControl may not even though they do share the same value.  Stepping through it with Snoop shows that the Height of the RowDefinition does change when moving the GridSplitter.